# Como baixar e exibir um arquivo sem que possa ser copiado

Tags: android, mobile, pdf

Considerando que possuo arquivos nos formatos `.epub`, `.mobi` e `.pdf` hospedados em um servidor.
Existe alguma maneira de baixar estes arquivos internamente em um aplicativo Android, de modo que os arquivos baixados não possam ser copiados pelos usuários e sejam exibidos pelo próprio aplicativo? O ideal seria poder mostrar o arquivo permitindo que o usuário possa interagir com mesmo, navegando por páginas e tópicos. Mesmo que esta funcionalidade seja terceirizada por outro aplicativo, porém mantendo a segurança.
Soluções que não sejam possíveis para todos formatos, também são válidas.

Comment: É possível sim, você pode armazenar o arquivo em formato blob direto no banco sqlite, porém, isso envolve bastante código, é estritamente necessário que os arquivos sejam sigilosos ou irá causar algum dolo se a pessoa ler fora da aplicação ? Creio que caiba essa questão, é muito mais rápido e demanda muito menos trabalho armazenar o arquivo no armazenamento do dispositivo e só armazenar o caminho para o mesmo.

Comment: Caso queira mesmo armazenar, essa questão em inglês tem uma implementação http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917338/how-do-i-open-a-pdf-from-a-blob-stored-in-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: Sim e necessário, são materiais pagos, não posso impedir o usuário de tirar print, porém copiar o arquivo nem pensar

Comment: Entendi, caso você tenha muita perca de performance inserindo o arquivo direto no banco, pode tentar gerar um pdf com restrições de leitura, cópia e etc.. o Doro PDF writer faz isso, daí você poderia salvar direto no dispositivo e na sua aplicação liberar uma senha de uso limitado (sem cópia e impressão), nunca testei, mas creio que deva funcionar no Android assim como nos Desktops